# Why does USCIS.gov still say "respond with evidence" online when I mailed it in?

Tags: uscis

When I go to my.uscis.gov and look under, *"I-485 Application to Register Permanent Residence or Adjust Status"* it says,

> "...Our records shows nothing is outstanding at this time. We will let you know if we need anything from you."

Followed by,

> Review the notice we sent and respond with the requested evidence by

I mailed in my evidence, since it required a sealed doctors notice. That means I can't use the web site to upload it. It also doesn't show the evidence as having been received? Do I need to call someone about this? What do I do when these two statements conflict?

Comment: Did you mail it using a service that includes proof of delivery?  If not, how long ago did you mail it?  If so, was it delivered?  If so, how long ago was it delivered?

Comment: @phoog I did, and it shows it as having been delivered but that's not something I trust much. It just shows the package got to the destination.

Comment: Well exactly.  But how long ago?  If it was delivered two days ago the soonest they could possibly process it is tomorrow, since today is a federal holiday.  On top of this, a delay of a few days or even weeks would not be particularly surprising for a government bureaucracy, considering that the thing has to get from the mail room to someone who can open it, understand what's inside, and then update your file accordingly.

Comment: I sent in the evidence in April.

Comment: Ok, you're still not answering the question about when they received it, but I suppose that it was a few days after you sent it, so either in April or early May, so I've upvoted the question.

Comment: They received it three days after i sent it.. it doesn't take USPS more than three days to deliver a piece of mail to my local field office. You're not focusing on the question though: regardless of when I sent it, when I see both of these statements on the website, how should i read it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case the evidence was received. I can't explain why the website said

> Review the notice we sent and respond with the requested evidence by

But they had the evidence sitting in their office. When I involved my local representative they promptly [found the evidence and approved everything (next day).](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/26895/13797)

Answer (score 2):

The most likely explanation is that it is sitting in a pile somewhere waiting for your case officer to get to it. The USCIS officers work on hundreds of cases concurrently, so once an RFE is issued, they put your case back into the pending pile, from which they pull cases to work on. Once your mailing arrives and is added to your case, it would then be marked ready for review again and wait for its turn for the officer to look at it again. Which is probably when the status of your case will change again.

Answer (score -1):

> Why does USCIS.gov still say "respond with evidence" online when I mailed it in?

USCIS sometimes takes a while to update it. Sources:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/USCIS/comments/ycsmvt/how_to_know_if_uscis_received_my_rfe/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/USCIS/comments/plmdu1/how_to_know_if_the_uscis_received_my_rfe_response/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/USCIS/comments/12dwxl2/how_long_did_it_take_for_you_to_get_rfe_has_been/

Comment: Discussion on Meta about this answer: [Why was "Note that this Reddit sub is way more informative than this Stack Exchange site." removed from my answer about USCIS?](https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/a/468/164)