# How to check if evidence mailed to the USCIS field office was received?

Tags: documentation, uscis

I was sent a notice that requested evidence. It asked I mail the evidence to a field office.

```
U.S. Citizenship and Immigration Services
Houston Field Office
810 Gears Rd. Suite 100
Houston, TX 77067
```

How can I check that the evidence was received? Does the field office have a phone number that is not the general 1-800 number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I ended up doing was going to my House of Representative's office. For me that's [Congressman Al Green](https://algreen.house.gov/). You have to fill out their intake paperwork, and after I did that they placed a call to an unlisted number reserved for Congressmen (which should be illegal, imho). I told them to look into this to see if the documents were received.

What actually happened was I got a call back saying "it was approved." **The next day.** And true to form, it took them like two weeks to send me the letter and another couple of weeks to send the green card. That was it. It as over.

Involve your Congressman's office. The system seems to be rigged to create a problem by them, that only they can fix.

---

Also, side note, all the Congressmen have offices that handle this stuff. And they all want to be sure they're the ones handling it exclusively. I would not panic and fill out the paperwork for all of them at the same time. I would do one, give them a week. Then I would try another representative.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I check that the evidence was received. Does the field office have a phone number that is not the general 1-800 number?

The field offices don't have direct numbers, but in the RFE you may have had a number mentioned which you could call. The general USCIS customer service number is (800) 375-5283.

Generally, when mailing things to the US government, you should use the USPS Certified Mail with Return Receipt service. The certified mail receipt is a legal proof of mailing, and the return receipt is the proof that the USCIS is in possession of your mailing. It won't protect you from interns losing stuff, but it does give you the documentation needed to later claim that you've been compliant, if needed. It may also help USCIS find your mail if it is indeed lost.

Comment: there is no way to get anything out of that number other than an sms or emailed link to the web page. you can't talk to anyone.

Comment: According to their website you should still be able to schedule an appointment via that number. But yes, I agree, the service experience is not stellar

Answer (score -2):

From https://www.reddit.com/r/USCIS/comments/plmdu1/how_to_know_if_the_uscis_received_my_rfe_response/:

> You can always check with USCIS via chat (EMMA) or call

Comment: Discussion on Meta about this answer: [Why was "Note that this Reddit sub is way more informative than this Stack Exchange site." removed from my answer about USCIS?](https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/a/468/164)